# Разная реакция на один и тот же редирект

Tags: .htaccess, apache, centos, redirect

Необходимо выполнить редирект со страниц старого сайта на новый.
В панели сервера в "Apache redirects". Прописал первый редирект:

```
Redirect permanent /news http://some.domain/blog
Redirect permanent /news/* /blog/
```

Все работает отлично, при переходе на news, редиректит на blog. При переходе на news/some так же редиректит на blog. Такое поведение и нужно.
При этом:

```
Redirect permanent /catalog http://some.domain/auction
Redirect permanent /catalog/* /auction/
```

в первом случае так же происходит правильный редирект. Во втором почему то при переходе /catalog/some, редиректит на /auction/some.

Чем может быть вызвано то, что одна и та же форма записи работает по разному. Если я не правильно прописываю, то как сделать, чтоб при переходе хоть на /catalog/some, хоть на /catalog/some/more, редиректило на /auction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, правильнее использовать RedirectMatch, а не Redirect:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/news http://some.domain/blog
RedirectMatch permanent ^/catalog http://some.domain/auction
```